# UIAlertView alert repeat three times within long press gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uialertview

I created an application. Through developing it, i used long press button to show an alert.

This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)longPressDetected1:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    //     label1.text = @"Select Iran to observe its historical data projections ";

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                    message:@"Press the blue button (+) to select your region "
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];    
}
```

Question: When I want to cancel the UIAlertView by using the cancelIbutton, I must press  this button three times to cancel the UIAlertView. it means UIAlterview cannot be canceled just by one press.
Could you please help me?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Sorry this is ipad app

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that your are showing more than one alert view. Your long press handler will get called for different states.

From the docs for `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`:

> Long-press gestures are continuous. The gesture begins (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) when the number of allowable fingers (numberOfTouchesRequired) have been pressed for the specified period (minimumPressDuration) and the touches do not move beyond the allowable range of movement (allowableMovement). The gesture recognizer transitions to the Change state whenever a finger moves, and it ends (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) when any of the fingers are lifted.

So you end up displaying an alert for the "Began" state, then the "Changed" state, and again for the "Ended" state. If you moved your finger around you would get a stream of "Changed" states and you would end up showing an alert for every one of them too.

You need to decide when you actually want the alert to appear. Do you want it to appear at the first "Changed" state or when the user lifts their finger and you get the "Ended" state.

Your code needs to be something like this:

```
- (IBAction)longPressDetected1:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        //     label1.text = @"Select Iran to observe its historical data projections ";

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                    message:@"Press the blue button (+) to select your region "
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
    }
}
```

This will show the alert when the user lifts their finger. Change `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` to `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` if you want the alert to appear as soon as the long press is recognized. But keep in mind you may still get multiples since a long press can generate multiple "Changed" states. In this case you need to add an additional check to only show the alert if there isn't already one.

Actually, here's an easy way to support a single alert on the "Changed" state:

```
- (IBAction)longPressDetected1:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        sender.enabled = NO; // Prevent any more state updates so you only get this one
        sender.enabled = YES; // reenable the gesture recognizer for the next long press

        //     label1.text = @"Select Iran to observe its historical data projections ";

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                    message:@"Press the blue button (+) to select your region "
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, when you want the alert to appear as soon as the long press is recognized, you need to compare with UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan, not ...Changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (IBAction)longPressDetected1:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
//     label1.text = @"Select Iran to observe its historical data projections ";

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                message:@"Press the blue button (+) to select your region "
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
alert.tag =10;
[alert show];    

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

  switch (alertView.tag)
{
    case 10:
        if (buttonIndex==0)
        {

        }
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem of showing multiple alert views or the need to tap Cancel three times?

Comment: i think u r using more then one alertview in viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I had a similar issue.

Any UILongPressGestureRecognizer will generate at least 4 changes of state:

- changed - (i.e. changed to started)
- began - (i.e. started)
- changed - (i.e. changed to ended)
- ended - (i.e. ended)

So to handle it well, you need to choose which of those conditions will activate an action.

The simplest, which sort of corresponds to 'touch up inside' for a UIButton is to detect the 'ended' state.

An example is below where 'longPress' is the instance of UILongPressGestureRecognizer

```
- (void)longPressedLastImage:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*) longPress {
    if (longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
       // do what you would in response to an equivalent button press 
    }
}
```

This lets you treat the continuous press more like the basic UIButton action.

'simple is better than complex' - T Peters - the Zen of Python