# UILongPressGestureRecognizer Show Alert On Textfield

Tags: ios, iphone, ios4, uigesturerecognizer, uialertview

I have a UILongPressGestureRecognizer added to a UITextField. When I press the UITextField it is show me alert but that is three alert show me.
That is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gs = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer      alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(AlertServer:)];
    gs.delegate = self;
    [_companyidTxt addGestureRecognizer:gs];
    [gs release];
}
-(void)AlertServer:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gs
{
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Okay", nil];
    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    myTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    myTextField.text=mainString;
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
    [alertView retain];
}
```

Can anyone explain why this happens, and how it can be prevented?
Thanx in advance

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319591/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-gets-called-twice-when-pressing-down and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243812/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-issue and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306942/uialertview-alert-repeat-three-times-within-long-press-gesture-recognizer?rq=1 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727203/longpress-on-iphone-app-opens-3-alerts-alertview-or-gesture-code-issue?rq=1    Please check other questions before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
-  (void)AlertServer:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender { 
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
       alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Okay", nil];
    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    myTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    myTextField.text=mainString;
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];

     }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
       NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.");
   //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration` based on your observations (The time interval is in seconds. The default duration is is 0.5 seconds.) or use some flag to check if Alert is already shown.